# Using First() get the 2nd item of LINQ result?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I'm new to Linq and EntityFramework. This is a sample program I met while learning them.

The data in table is like this:

```
BlogId  Title
1       Hello Blog
2       New Blog
3       New Blog
```

I have the following Linq code, trying to read the first blog id(expected to be 2):

```
var name = "New Blog";
var blogs = (from b in db.Blogs
                where b.Title == name
                orderby b.Title
                select b);//.ToList();

Console.Write("The first id: ");
Console.WriteLine(blogs.First().BlogId);
```

The result comes out to be 3.

Then I use *ToList()*:

```
var blogs = (from b in db.Blogs
                where b.Title == name
                orderby b.Title
                select b).ToList();
Console.Write("The first id: ");
Console.WriteLine(blogs.First().BlogId);
```

The result comes out to be 2.

Can anyone help to explain this? Or is this a bug?

Thanks.

//////////////////////// **UPDATE** /////////////////////////////

I just deleted the data in the database and inserted some new items. Now the table is like this:

```
BlogId  Title
5       New Blog
6       New Blog
7       New Blog
8       New Blog
```

Then I ran the program above(Not with ToList()), the First() method returns the id **6**
So I assume the method always returns the **2nd** item in the situation above. And it doesn't seem to have anything to do with the RDBMS. Can anyone explain?

Thanks.

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////

FYI, the following is the whole .cs file:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using System.Data.Entity;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace SampleNew
{
    class Program
    {
        public class Blog
        {
            [Key]
            public Int32 BlogId { get; set; }
            public String Title { get; set; }
            public virtual List<Post> Posts { get; set; } 
        }

        public class Post
        {
            [Key]
            public Int32 PostId { get; set; }
            public String Title{ get; set; }

            public String Content { get; set; }
        }

        public class BlogContext : DbContext
        {
            public DbSet<Blog> Blogs{ get; set; }

            public DbSet<Post> Posts { get; set; }
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (var db = new BlogContext())
            {
                // Create and save a new Blog 
                // Console.Write("Enter a name for a new Blog: ");
                var name = "New Blog";

                //var blog = new Blog { Title = name };
                var blogs = (from b in db.Blogs
                             where b.Title == name
                             orderby b.Title
                             select b).ToList();

                Console.Write("The first id: ");
                Console.WriteLine(blogs.First().BlogId);

                Console.WriteLine(blogs.Count());

                Blog blog = null;
                foreach (Blog b in blogs)
                {
                    blog = b;
                    Console.WriteLine(blog.BlogId);
                }
                Console.WriteLine(blog.BlogId);

                Console.WriteLine(blogs.First().BlogId);
                Console.WriteLine(blogs.First().BlogId);

                Console.WriteLine(blogs.Last().BlogId);
                Console.WriteLine(blogs.Last().BlogId);


                blog.Posts = new List<Post>();
                var post = new Post { Content = "Test Content2", Title = "Test Title2"};
                blog.Posts.Add(post);

                db.Posts.Add(post);
                db.SaveChanges();

                // Display all Blogs from the database 
                var query = from b in db.Blogs
                            orderby b.Title
                            select b;

                Console.WriteLine("All blogs in the database:");
                foreach (var item in query)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(item.Title);
                }

                Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit...");
                Console.ReadKey();
            } 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please don't "beg a bug" in titles.

Comment: Why in heck did you *change* the title? That's *not what you are trying to do* and it's stated as a task, not an issue.

Comment: I meant to ask why I always got the 2nd result with the method First().

Comment: "And it doesn't seem to have anything to do with the RDBMS." It has everything to do with RDBMS. Here is a [link to a quick demo on sqlfiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/cd9c9/3) that should bring some clarity to the subject. The first query returns the data in "natural" order; the second (with `TOP 1`) returns the second row.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You've got two identical titles there, but with different IDs. Your RDBMS has the flexibility of returning the rows that correspond to your `'New Blog'` in any order that it wishes, because your code does not specify anything beyond the requirement to order by the title. Moreover, it is not even required to return results in the same order each time that you run the same query.

If you would like predictable results, add a "then by" to your LINQ statement to force the ordering that you wish to have:

```
var query = from b in db.Blogs
    orderby b.Title, b.BlogId
    select b;
```

**EDIT :**

> When I ran the program above, the `First()` method returns the id `6` so I assume the method always returns the 2nd item in the situation above. And it doesn't seem to have anything to do with the RDBMS. Can anyone explain?

That's also happening in RDBMS, and it is reproducible without LINQ. Here is a small demo ([link to sqlfiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/cd9c9/3)):

```
create table blogs(blogid int,title varchar(20));
insert into blogs(blogid,title) values (5,'New blog');
insert into blogs(blogid,title) values (6,'New blog');
insert into blogs(blogid,title) values (7,'New blog');
insert into blogs(blogid,title) values (8,'New blog');
SELECT * FROM Blogs ORDER BY Title
```

This query produces results in "natural" order:

```
BLOGID  TITLE
------  --------
5       New blog
6       New blog
7       New blog
8       New blog
```

However, this query, which is what EF runs to get the `First()` item in RDBMS

```
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM Blogs ORDER BY Title
```

returns the *second* row in natural order:

```
BLOGID  TITLE
------  --------
6       New blog
```

It does not mean that it is going to return the same row in other RDBMSs ([link to a demo with MySQL returning a different row for the same query](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cd9c9/1)), or even in the same RDBMS. It simply demonstrates that LINQ relies on RDBMS for the selection of the row, and the RDBMS returns an arbitrarily selected row.

Comment: But would it be predictable if I use ToList()?

Comment: @Soony Once it's in the list, yes, the ordering is predictable. But the issue happens well before the `ToList` call - it happens even before the data gets into your program from the database, because the ordering of equal items is decided, arbitrarily, inside your RDBMS.

Comment: @Soony (Even if ToList was used before the OrderBy, the items in the list may already be "out of order".)

Comment: @dasblinkenlight I just inserted another record into the table. Now I have 3 records with the same title 'New Blog'. But the First() method still gives the id 3. Why? Shouldn't it be 4?

Comment: More than likely, that's because the query result is being cached by the database. Try restarting your SQL Server instance and see what happens. Really, this is a matter of the query using an order by against a field that has multiple repeated values.

Comment: I updated the question. Please pay attention to the updated part. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the difference comes in the optimizations that are taken by First() without the ToList().

When you call ToList(), the entire ordered list must be created. So it will order everything using an efficient sort algorithm.

However, with First(), it only needs to find the min value. So it can use a much more effecient algorithm that basically goes through the enumerable once and stores the current min object value. (So it will result in the first object of the min value).

This is a different algorithm then sorting the entire list and hence gets a different result.

Update:
Also, this being a database, it may be using linq to sql which will produce a different query based on the above description (getting a sorted list vs getting the first with the min value).

Comment: The "optimizations" occur entirely because it *is* from a database. The OrderBy from LINQ-to-Object is a *stable* sort (and this situation would not exist if the original source was a List); but no such guarantee is made by the underlying database (or LINQ provider), as in this case. The materialization of the list, while it changes the observed behavior, *does not change the lack of stability guarantees*. I suspect the same results would result from the equivalent (plain select or select with top/limit) against the database - it comes down to the database *query plan* used.

Comment: Ok, thanks. So my description is explaining what is occuring inside the database in response to the various queries rather than what is happening in dotnet. (The original question indicates the results are predictable an repeatable, so this is a possible attempt at explaining why the db is returning the predictable though unexpected - not random -results)

Comment: Just because the OP is able to obtain "repeatable" results does not mean the behavior is guaranteed - *both* results are correct, and neither is guaranteed to remain the same. (Adding a new index or recompiling the query plan may trigger a different ordering, for instance.)

Comment: Of course, nothing is guaranteed. But if it is repeatable (even for a shot time), there should be an explanation - which I believe is the purpose of the OP's question.